# Cannot define clusters in IBM BigInsights for Apache Hadoop

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights

I can not start working with IBM BigInsights for Apache Hadoop on BLuemix.

I cannot click on manage clusters or define clusters. When I click, I get the information that page is not available.

Regards,

Srdjan

Comment: Hi Srdjan. Can you try again? I was just able to begin the process of creating a cluster through the BigInsights for Apache Hadoop service.

Comment: No it does not work, simply no page available.

I have all the permissions possible but I can not manage or define any clusters, while the colleague who created the workspace can create a cluster..

Comment: There is likely something else going on here. Please submit a ticket so our support team can help you resolve this issue.
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#support

Answer (score 0):

We have seen some problems on this service in the past days. Now it should be resolved. Please double-check and in the negative case open a ticket to Bluemix Support.